# Automatically add #pragma once to header files

Tags: c++, clang, pragma, boilerplate

I try to remove every unnecessary boilerplate code from my personal projects. The first thing, I have noticed, is first line of every header files #pragma once. Not so surprising.
However, I would like to ask my compiler (clang SVN HEAD version) to automatically add this line to my header files (for example with a pattern like this: src/*.hpp). I think there are very rare cases when you actually want to include one header multiple times.

1. Do you agree?
2. Is there any existing solution for this problem?
3. Do you think this is a good idea?

With clang tools this issue can be solved, but I need some little help to start this extension.

1. Which clang tool should I use?

Theoretical usage of this tool/extension:

`clang --auto-pragma-once src/*.hpp src/*.cpp -o test`

Thank you for any advice

EDIT:

1. I do not want to store this pragma once in my file. So any editor or any other tools which place new things in the files are not working for this problem.
2. This topic is about the one-time inclusion of header files, not the pragma once.

Answer (score 2):

Just bite the bullet and put the pragma in your header files. It's only one line and if there is nothing, it might confuse others who look at your files.

Comment: And don't forget the include guards, which are still needed (at least if you ever want to port the code elsewhere---`#pragma once` is very non-standard).

Comment: @JamesKanze True, I assumed (perhaps incorrectly) if he was using the pragma he knows the implications..

Comment: @JamesKanze: It's non-standard but at least supported by recent versions Visual C++, G++ and Clang so you can cover a wider range of platforms already.

Comment: @JamesKanze define "very" non-standard. Yes, it's not in the C++ standard, but it's supported by common compilers (MSVC, gcc, clang, Intel, and some more)

Comment: @thokra Does it actually work in all of those environments?  It's not usually supported on Unix platforms, because it can't be made to work reliably with networked drives, at least the way NFS (and I'm pretty sure CRB as well) works.  (That is _why_ it isn't in the standard.)

Comment: @JamesKanze Why cannot the compiler replace #pragma once with the text for a regular header guard with a unique generated symbol when parsing the text?

Comment: @JamesKanze: What I can say is that it works perfectly on x86[/64] machines on Linux(g++/clang), Windows (VS2010) and OSX(clang) with local data.

Comment: @NeilKirk Because it won't know later that it's the same file.

Comment: @thokra But who compiles local data?  At the very least, your libraries will be on a remote machine.  (And I'll have to give it a try on my Linux box at home.  Determining whether two files are the same under Unix is decidedly non-trivial, since a file can, and many do, have several names.)

Comment: This topic is not about especially about pragma once. It is about one-time inclusion of header files.

Comment: @JamesKanze: I don't know your setup but where I'm currently working, we do. I think you can't generalize it like this.

Comment: @thokra Where I work, we build on the local drives, but it's 100% Windows (and I use `#pragma once`).  Over my career, however, I've worked a lot more under Unix than Windows, and I've never seen a Unix box where the home directories were local.

Comment: @JamesKanze: See? We're about 95% Windows. For the rest, local /home setup is sufficient. But in general you're probably right.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you'd want to use clang for this.  It depends
on the editor, but every editor I know allows you to trigger on
things like opening a new file whose name matches a specific
pattern, and insert boilerplate in it.  In industry, it's pretty
much forbidden not to use this, since that's how the copyright
notices get inserted.  In my case, for example, if I create
a new file with the name xyz.hh, the editor comes up with

```
/****************************************************************************/
/*      File:       xyz.hh                                                  */
/*      Author:     J. Kanze                                                */
/*      Date:       25/09/2013                                              */
/*      Copyright ....                                                      */
/* ------------------------------------------------------------------------ */

#ifndef xyz_hh_20130925QPIvFK6xMJYLBhSpv58ROPOU
#define xyz_hh_20130925QPIvFK6xMJYLBhSpv58ROPOU

#endif
//  Local Variables:                        --- for emacs
//  mode: c++                               --- for emacs
//  tab-width: 8                            --- for emacs
//  End:                                    --- for emacs
//  vim: set ts=8 sw=4 et filetype=cpp:     --- for vim
```

If I do this in my work domain, the copyright notice is
different, the include guards follow a different standard, and
there's also a #pragma once.

Comment: But this solution the inserted information later stored in the file. I do not want this. Maybe my question was misleading.

Comment: @BalázsÁrva But what do you want then?  You can't have the compiler treat every file as if it contained a `#pragma once`, because this would break the standard library (which has at least one header which must be included multiple times).

Comment: Yes, I understand this would break the standard library. That why I added the pattern to sample compiler invocation. The matched files are included only once automatically. So the standard library and any other files would not be affected by this behavior.