# How to automatically write #pragma once after creating header file in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

There is one similarly formulated question [Automatically add #pragma once to header files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19010913/automatically-add-pragma-once-to-header-files)

However, the author was looking for a compiler related solution to reinforce `#pragma once`.

In contrast, I just want to have every new `.h/.hpp` file start with `#pragma once`, as it is implemented in MS Visual Studio.

Although trivial, I really miss this feature and I couldn't find it in settings. Is it even possible?

Comment: you can use the extension [File Templates](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.vscode-file-templates)

Comment: Related/duplicate: [How can I create templates for file extensions in Visual Studio Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50571130/how-can-i-create-templates-for-file-extensions-in-visual-studio-code)

Comment: Thanks for quick response! I couldn't find this extension, because I wasn't even using `template` keyword while searching.

Comment: note that this answer on the question you link https://stackoverflow.com/a/19011056/4117728, specifically addresses your question (ie not use the compiler, but add the line to the files)